# Enable CORS at Visual Studio Code

Tags: cors, visual-studio-code

I´m unable to start debugger on Visual Studio Code and also CORS extension on chrome, it simply does not appears as when I console yarn start.

Is it any way to specify that I want CORS extension enabled on Chrome when debugging?

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can instruct the Chrome instance to allow CORS by starting it with the argument `--disable-web-security`. To do this from VS Code, use the `runtimeArgs` config option, i.e.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"]
        }
    ]
}
```